# Help me identify these two ants

Tags: species-identification, entomology, ant

I recently found these two winged ants near a colony. There were 5, but 3 flew away.

Location: Nassau/The Bahamas. November 19, 2017.

Are they queens? And What species?

[image] [image]

Comment: The square head and the distance between the abdomen and the thorax lead to Myrmecinae, probably Pheidole, Pheidologeton/Carrebara or some granivorous species.